# Mounting a glass panel on drywall over concrete

Tags: drywall, concrete

I am trying to mount a 2'x3' glass whiteboard that weighs ~14lbs to the wall in a new condo.  Best I can tell, there is a concrete barrier very close to the surface drywall, and it isn't giving me enough room to install drywall anchors.

I'm open to doing pretty much anything to get this thing mounted, but I don't know what my best bet would be here.  Should I look into drilling into the concrete?  Is there a better way?

I own the place and am completely OK with doing something irreversible to the wall.

Bonus points: I'm playing with the idea of adding a bike rack to the wall as well so any solution that would let me mount significantly more than 14lb (and I could use for the bike) would be awesome!

Comment: Is there a gap behind the drywall?

Comment: There is a small gap, but not much of one.  I don't have exact measurements but I'd guess ~1-2cm

Comment: Well, it doesn't take much of one to have the drywall collapse when you mount your item or place weight on it.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but I thought that was the whole point of drywall anchors: for mounting (relatively) light items on drywall w/o using studs.  Or perhaps I misunderstand what you're getting at here.

Comment: True, but the proposed solution doesn't use hollow-wall anchors, and you yourself said they won't work. You also asked about mounting heavier items.

Comment: Gotcha.  So this is more of a concern that if I drill into the wall the drywall might not hold up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86768/discussion-between-graham-and-isherwood).

Comment: Right, if you snug your fasteners down too much or you don't do that but mount something very heavy.

Answer (score 4):

I'd drill into the concrete and use some sort of masonry anchors, wall plugs should be sufficient for the white board because it goes close to the wall.

For a bicycle something stronger is needed, because it's heavier and mounts further form the wall. I'd go with expanding bolts. 10mm seems a good size.

Or just drill into the wall an glue  steel bars in with a 2-part resin. (Chemset, builders filler etc), then put somethign over the bars to make them look nice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I'll ask condo management what the building's policy is for drilling into the walls.  I know some of my neighbours have done it, but I want to make sure I don't do anything particularly daft.